# rails application doesn't load css/js/images in production-environment

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3, production-environment

when i run my rails application in production mode images are not displayed and css is not working 
in my console i got the message
**ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/stylesheets/theme.css"):
Rendered C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (0.0ms)**
but in my view/layout application.html.erb i included the line **<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'theme' %>** and theme.css is present in the public/stylesheet folder

Answer (score 5, accepted):

make the following change in **config/production.rb**

change:

```
config.serve_static_assets = false
```

to:

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

That will fix it, I guarantee