# CSS doesn't load in production - everything fine in dev (Rails 4.1, Capistrano 3; bootstrap), update: nginx config issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, deployment, nginx, capistrano3

Problem is as follows: Everything works fine in development, but when I deploy my rails app to production, the site works in plain html, but CSS (bootstrap) doesn't get loaded (JS probably also not).

Sorry, I looked for 2 days at ~15 possible solutions and could not make it work...

**Update:** After following @rich-peck's advice, it looks like it's a server issue. Updated with nginx config

My setup:

- Ruby 2.1.2, Rails 4.1
- Rbenv
- mysql2 as db
- Bootstrap 3
- Ubuntu 14.04 on Server with nginx and passenger
- Capistrano 3 for deployment

Config as follows - production.rb:

```
config.cache_classes = true
config.eager_load = true
config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
config.serve_static_assets = true
config.assets.compress = true
config.assets.compile = false
config.assets.digest = true
config.assets.version = '1.0'
config.log_level = :info
config.assets.precompile << /(^[^_\/]|\/[^_])[^\/]*$/
config.i18n.fallbacks = true
config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
```

Capfile:

```
require 'capistrano/setup'
require 'capistrano/deploy'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rails'
require 'capistrano/rbenv'
set :rbenv_type, :user
set :rbenv_custom_path, '/home/deploy/.rbenv/'
set :rbenv_ruby, '2.1.2'
Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake').each { |r| import r }
```

in application.rb:

```
...
# Enable the asset pipeline
config.assets.enabled = true
...
```

application.css.scss:

```
/* ...
*= require_self
*= require_tree .
*/

@import "bootstrap";
@import "custom";
@import "exchange_rates";
@import "contacts";
```

This is what I tried (among many others):

```
# on dev machine and server /current:
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

see [Link Custom CSS and Javascript to Rails After Deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17021635/link-custom-css-and-javascript-to-rails-after-deployment)

in configs:

```
config.serve_static_assets = true # tried false
config.assets.compile = false     # tried true
```

see [rails application doesn't load css/js/images in production-environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6690892/rails-application-doesnt-load-css-js-images-in-production-environment)

production.log doesn't throw any errors, except for pages with js.

Also read a lot about the Rails Asset Pipeline and nginx server setup, but couldn't figure it out... Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

**Update: nginx server config**

Originally, I followed the very helpful and clear deploy tutorial at gorails: https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/14.04

However, nginx wasn't starting correctly so I updated the config files (with help from SO) as follows:

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:

```
events {
  worker_connections  4096;  ## Default: 1024
}

http {
    ##
    # Phusion Passenger
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed ruby-passenger or ruby-passenger-enterprise
    ##
    passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
    passenger_ruby /home/deploy/.rbenv/shims/ruby;
    passenger_nodejs /usr/bin/nodejs;
    server {
            listen 80 default_server;
            listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

            server_name <URL>;
            passenger_enabled on;
            rails_env    production;
            root         /home/deploy/<PROJECT_NAME>/current/public;

            # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
            error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
                root   html;
            }
    }
}
```

*(URL and PROJECT_NAME redacted in question)*

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default I could keep empty, and with this I got nginx to run smoothly - except for this problem with the assets. Does any one have any advice?

Comment: Have you done `bundle install` in your production environment?

Comment: Yes, thanks, I do it regularly :-)

Comment: In my case it was in `config/environments/production.rb` that `config.action_controller.asset_host` was set to the wrong server (wrong url).

Answer (score 5):

Several things to test:

> - When you precompile your assets, do the required files appear in your `public` directory?

When you `precompile` your assets, you basically tell the Rails asset pipeline to merge & compile all your assets in the `public` directory. This means if you're trying to include a particular file in your production asset pipeline, it *should* be precompiled

I would run the `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` command, and then look at all your assets in the `public` folder to check if they're there

--

> - If the assets are present in your `public` folder, are they being pushed to the server?

You should `SSH` into your server & browse to the `public` directory of your app (in `/current`). This will allow you to see if your assets have been uploaded to your server as you need

If they are not there, the problem is with Capistrano's deploy process; if they *are* there, it means there's a problem with your Rails server

--

> - If the assets *are* in the `public` folder on your server, it will mean the server is at fault somehow

Probably the best way to ensure it's not a server issue is to reload the server. With `apache`, you'll typically use `service reload apache2`, but I'm not sure about `nginx`.

This should be accompanied by looking at your Rails installation - is it calling the correct `assets` as defined in your `config` files?

Comment: Thank you, that was super-helpful!! Turns out the assets are both present on the dev machine as well as on the server. So I was looking in the wrong place the entire time and it is indeed a nginx/server issue. I will update the question with the server config - again, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit off topic, but for organization's sake you might want to put your Nginx server block in /etc/nginx/sites-available/default and then make sure you have it linked to /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default.

It should work fine with the server block in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf but it's best practice to put it in the default host or create another virtual host if you so desire.

Glad you were able to get things working.